# How to prevent NSManagedObjectContext from corrupting the database when a thread gets killed while saving?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

[In this question, octy wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202976/why-should-i-prefer-to-create-an-nsmanagedobjectcontext-for-every-new-thread-or-n):

> BTW, if you save on a background
>   thread, you also need to consider what
>   happens when your app is terminated
>   while a save operation is in progress.
>   Background threads get killed right
>   away, whereas the watchdog waits 5
>   seconds for the main thread to finish
>   up.

Now I've spent all day implementing NSOperation and creating NSManagedObjectContext instances directly inside the NSOperation subclasses so every NSOperation owns it's own non-shared MOC. But now this is very bad news since a scenario like this, which likely happens all the time, would corrupt the Core Data database. I mean it can't start to write a half byte of something in the sqlite3 file and then just stop right away.

And then there's another problem: In my NSOperations I also do File I/O with NSFileManager.

So what can I do about this? Must I keep track of all running NSOperations and NSOperationQueues in my app und take care of them quickly in the App Delegate when the app gets terminated, so that I can tell the NSOperations to SFF (Save F*****g Fast) or cancel all operations, grab their MOC's and "hard-save" them immediately? What's best practice to solve this problem?

And why am I hearing about this the first time in my career? I mean none of the NSOperationQueue and Core Data mentioning books even talks about this but it seems it's a random app killer that forces the user to re-install (and possibly lose tons of data) if we don't take explicit care of this.

Comment: I developed this NSOperation subclass to do what you say https://github.com/veritech/FRCoreDataOperation. During the average run of my application i'll create well over a 100 of these running in a serial NSOperationQueue. And i cancel all operations whenever the application is terminated/backgrounded and I've never had problems with corruption. Feel free to look at the class, and perhaps it might help you.

Comment: You have to cancel it *right in the middle of a saving operation* as it can happen in reality. That's the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main power of MOC is that represents an abstract storage that is independent from the format. It stores all it's objects in the memory and uses the mechanism of transactions to commit any changes. So when you're inserting/deleting/editing some objects that in MOC they are only changed in memory and not in persistent store (whether it is SQLite database, XML file or whatever). The changes are only committed when you call `save:` method.

As for NSOperation and file handling: if you want to stop some operation, you should call `cancel` for that. From docs:

> This method does not force your
>   operation code to stop. Instead, it
>   updates the object’s internal flags to
>   reflect the change in state. If the
>   operation has already finished
>   executing, this method has no effect.
>   Canceling an operation that is
>   currently in an operation queue, but
>   not yet executing, makes it possible
>   to remove the operation from the queue
>   sooner than usual.

It means that if there is some IO operation running when you're canceling an operation operation would wait until it is finished.

Also despite the Core Data transaction mechanism you should implement your own one for any data that is not managed by it (if needed).

Comment: My question wasn't clear enough: When the thread gets killed and the MOC *is saving right now*, wouldn't this corrupt the database? How can the MOC save to the store without corrupting it's integrity or data when the thread (which the MOC is operating in) gets killed from one nanosecond to another?

Comment: saving process is also a transaction. So if it is cancelled during the execution, then all changes are discarded and nothing is corrupted.